# Conditional parameter for curried function based on generic

Tags: typescript

How to make the params conditional only if no generic supplied?

```
type Params<T> = T extends Record<string, string> ? T : never;

export const getPath =
  <T>(path: string) =>
  (params: Params<T>) => {
    const lang = getCurrentLang();

    return generatePath(path, { lang, ...(params ?? {}) });
  };
```

For example:

```
const login = getPath("/:lang/login")
login() // should works without types error

const book = getPath<{ id: string }>("/:lang/books/:id")
book() // error
book({ id: "1" }) // works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics in combination with a conditional type to enforce a certain return type for `getPath()`. Let your generic parameter `T` extend a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of your conditional return value and something that is not assinable to that value (e. g. `undefined`) so you can check if a generic argument was passed or not.

If a generic argument was passed, return `(param: T) => ...` otherwise just `() => ...`.
This logic can be simplified even more using tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions: 
 `(...params: T extends Record<string, string> ? [T] : [] ) => any`

```
export const getPath = <
  T extends Record<string, string> | undefined = undefined
>(
  path: string
): ((
  ...params: T extends Record<string, string> ? [T] : []
) => any) => {
  return null as any; // ignoring the implemetation
};

const login = getPath("/:lang/login");
login(); // works

const book = getPath<{id: string}>("/:lang/books/:id");
//    ^? const book: (param: {id: string;}) => any
book(); // error
book({id: "1"}); // works
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgBQIYwAWcAvHADwCwAUHHACpygzDIAmqcASsElG+XRQAlsgwAaOENEYAfHAA+cAK7tgAM1HA2pFWs3JtNWQAoadMAUIAuKTBFiaASlsmztOADpvlqHgC2qLaMzKwc3LzQAtJikjFycAD8cADa9AC6cLYp6c6k8njIAJ5O+XAA3uZwUNjKUMhwyMoANs1weJyFRQDccAD0fXDCGMjQMnBEwEP+YM3A-tgEwig0AL7dNDRIaPDNEBiiuli4ViYARH3WzYUYfXsHyGdOG9T3oibP-YMA7tAA1qhNtRtug4AAjCAQP5HbD4IjkcrCNi2eKrUwXK43PoQqGoS5Ip4vAZ0OgAPWSIPgOL+rl8AVsiORdgcGG6q1KJAKxRo1I+vWJwCgUGgPMhfxMjNsZwAjGd2fyfv9AdQgA)

---

P. S. Note, I removed the function implementation as I don't know how `getCurrentLang()` and `generatePath()` are defined or what their return type is.